# Python lxml - creating different forks of tree

Tags: python, tree, lxml, xml.etree

I am trying to open an xml file using lxml, edit the xml and then save out different versions, but I can't get it working. The first save is meant to remove the  section, but the second save is meant to leave them in, currently save 1 correctly removes the  section, but so does save 2, which is meant to leave it in. What am I doing wrong? Here's a code example:

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse(pathToXmlFile, parser)
root = tree.getroot()

etree1 = etree
tree1 = tree
etree1.strip_elements(tree1, 'products')
tree1.write(pathToXmlFileOut1, pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, encoding = 'UTF-8')

etree2 = etree
tree2 = tree
tree2.write(pathToXmlFileOut2, pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `tree1` and `tree2` are the same object (pointing to the same object in memory). So you can't modify one variable without modifying the other. In example:

```
print tree1 == tree2  # True
print tree1 is tree2  # True
```

Maybe you could save first `tree2` without modifying it and then save `tree1` with the modification. Or maybe use a copy function to create two different objects.

Comment: Thanks, used tree1 = copy.deepcopy(tree) which works a treat.